# Introduce yourselves here

Tags: discussion

So I'm curious: what area of geoscience do you study, and where do you study it? What is your background and what is your general story?

Comment: And yourself? I am just as curious.

Answer (score 13):

My name is Gerrit Holl and I work as a researcher at the German Weather Service (DWD).  My PhD was on atmospheric remote sensing of ice clouds, using scientific and operational satellites, and my current work is to prepare the weather service for the next generation of geostationary satellites.  I have a broad interest in Earth sciences but a particular interest for the science of the atmosphere of Earth and other planets.

Answer (score 12):

I'm Simon. I'm a PhD student in Scotland, looking at regional-scale hydrodynamic modelling as applied to tidal stream energy. User of the MIKE modelling suite.

Answer (score 12):

I am Peter and can be labelled as a glaciologist. I study glaciers and climate as well as glacier and ice sheet dynamics and hydrology. Otherwise, I am employed and involved in all things academic at the university.

Answer (score 11):

I'm Scott. I am finishing up an MSc in geology and will be focusing on computational geodynamics for my PhD starting this fall quarter. My interests are far in wide, but most notably the modeling of dynamics at tectonic margins. I'm currently developing on CitcomS, but will be switching to ASPECT.

Answer (score 11):

My name is Brian Knight, and I have a MS in Geological Sciences from The University of Texas, USA. My career has moved into software since graduation, but I still remain interested in a variety of topics such as geomorphology, meteorology, petrology, and climatology.

It's always great to be part of a group with such diverse backgrounds.

Answer (score 10):

I studied tectonics at the University of Innsbruck. Hope this page will evolve into a great repository for earth science knowledge. I am also active on Wikipedia and Wikidata. And currently I am learning Python 3.

Answer (score 10):

I'm EnergyNumbers, and I work on climate change mitigation, as a researcher at a university and through some consultancy work.

Answer (score 10):

I studied archaeology in Plzeň, Czech Republic, and I work as a freelancing expert on computer (mostly GIS and database) applications in archaeology. Czech archaeology is very focused on our small central-european sandbox, but I've learnt few interresting details on broader history, and even few things from earth sciences. Hope I will be able to help the community with that!

Answer (score 10):

I'm working on a Ph.D. in physics at the University of Florida and expect to graduate at the end of summer.  I've never formally studied earth science beyond the high school level, but I am an outdoor enthusiast and avid rock collector.  The largest piece of art in my house is a 5' x 8' geologic map of the United States with a separate 5' x 3' legend.

Answer (score 9):

Area of Study: N/A

Place of Study: N/A

Interests: Geomagnetism, climatology, evolutionary biology

I'm a software engineer and process analyst for a major aerospace and defense company. I enjoy researching all areas of science in my spare time. See my user bio for more.

Answer (score 9):

My name is Matteo. I have a Ph.D. in Computer Science and I've been working on Energy & Meteorology/Climate since 2011. Given my background, I've a good knowledge about climate data analysis and data mining. Currently I use R and MATLAB as primary tools.

Answer (score 8):

My name is Drew, and I have a BS in Atmospheric Science from the University of Utah. I am an operational meteorologist with the US National Weather Service/NOAA. I'm primarily interested in meteorology, air chemistry, hydrology, climatology, geology, biogeochemistry, remote sensing, computer modeling, statistics and general computer science.

I am not a huge weather nerd despite my occupation.  I find meteorology as equally interesting as my other pursuits.

Answer (score 5):

My name is Damien, I have a PhD in Atmospheric Radiation Physics (Ultraviolet).  But, I am also qualified as an Economic Geologist and Climatologist.

Currently, I work in a high school, teaching senior Physics, Chemistry, Maths and do Science Outreach to all, young and old.  I am also an Adjunct Lecturer for a major Australian University - where I still pursue research in the applications of smartphone image sensors for atmospheric research (see my profile for my ResearchGate link).

I am a volcanology-nerd, have been since I was a kid - apparently my first word was 'lava'

Comment: Incidentally, my real life nickname is Sabre Tooth

Answer (score 3):

My real name is Zack Brink, and I'm an 8th grader at Robious Middle School. :) I'm a curious learner, and I love Stackexchange! I can be sort of naive when it comes to accepting answers, but I make sure to do research on the answer before accepting it for that reason. :D

I'm hoping to become a biologist when I grow up :)

Comment: Interesting, your bio says you're 21. Here's a glimpse of it `I'm Eevee. I'm a 21-year-old man with a PHD in Earth Science and Astronomy, a boy scout troop guide for troop 1829, a philosopher, I work part-time at Robious Middle School as a science teacher, and I have four years of experience in JavaScript.`

Comment: Darn, I would love an explanation for that. @Eevee

Answer (score 2):

My Name is Daniel, I did my PhD in Atmospheric Science (atmospheric chemistry) at the Helmholtz Center Geesthacht and the University of Hamburg, Germany.

I did some minor research on marine litter in the past. Currently, I work as PostDoc on atmospheric impacts on marine biogeochemistry at the Leibniz-Institute for Baltic Sea Research.

My focus is more on technical aspects like modeling and data processing.

Answer (score 2):

My name is Manuel. I graduated in geology in 2015 at Spain. I followed a course of oceanography in Bordeux, France. I didn't find a job in geology and I applied for a public work on administration. I earn a medium salary and my job is fix.

I have no expertize knowledges. I was a poor student very lazy, it took me 10 years to graduate. Aswell as being a lazy student, I am handicapped because of a menthal illness. I am diagnosed of schizzoaffective disorder and a psychiatry told I was low grade Asperger too, but psychiatrists at public health are not good and what I think I have is low grade [Complex Post Traumatic Stress Disorder](https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-to-have-complex-post-traumatic-disorder-CPTSD) with dissociation episodies as my psychotic episodies are related with my exposition to trauma.

I like to program and I have published this [mineral guide with quiz for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geologyapplications.minerals) devices. If you see any mistake in the database, specially in the environments of formation, you can sugest me modifications.

Comment: Manuel, welcome & contribute any way you can.

Comment: @Fred Thank you very much!

Comment: @Fred Congratulations for reaching top one reputation position!

Comment: @Fred I found this [english text corrector](https://www.deepl.com/write). I am going to pass my posts to evitate take more of your time. Thank you very much for all the edits you have done in my texts.

Answer (score 1):

I am Aureliano, I own a couple of patents related to High Pressure - High Temperature wells useful to oil production, as well as shale and geothermal activities, not mentioning uranium production. 
I am a born German-speaker, but most of my activity happened in SE-Asia, where we drilled horizontal wells up to 5km long.

I have a degree in physics, then further education in rock mechanics and energy production.

I am impressed by how much oil&gas we burned in the past 150 years and how little we achieved.

Comment: I guess we turned some into plastic also, and kept much of its carbon from entering the atmosphere by infusing it everywhere else in the ecosystem and doing our "civic duty" of making the [anthropocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropocene) easier for future alien explorers to recognize. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am a PhD holder, and currently working as a researcher in an Australian university.

I specialise in mineralogy, petrology, and geochemistry.