# Provisional Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

### How do you become a provisional moderator for this site?

Soon after the site launches into "public beta," the Community Team will appoint *provisional moderators* from this community until the community is ready to hold its own elections (once it graduates from beta). This is the official nominations thread that SE will use for selection moderators.

---

### What do moderators gain?

> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
>   as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
>   after the Beta period. Besides the normal abilities of a Moderator,
>   they will:
>
> 1. Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> 2. Organize the process of selecting the site’s attributes (the [help center], site scope, tags, etc.).
> 3. Rally community support and drive the mission of getting publicity for the site.
>
> Essentially, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for
>   anything we can do to help their sites succeed!**

---

### Here's what you should have to be a moderator here:

- Have a decent reputation and participate actively on meta
- Be well spoken, polite, professional, and a natural leader.
- **Be trusted.** You'll have a lot of data that a standard user won't. There'll be IPs, deleted posts, *complete* histories, and email addresses. You will have to handle them wisely and follow the terms and privacy policy of SE.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in **[A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)**.

Bonus points for:

- Moderator or high-reputation on other sites
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

---

### To nominate:

**Please break it down into one section for each item listed below.** You can nominate yourself or another person... don't be afraid to brag. Although humble moderators are better, we would rather not pass up a better candidate because they didn't want to sound audacious. That being said, a fine line still remains between selling yourself and being arrogant.

1. Post an answer containing the URLs to the user's/your **main *and* meta profiles on Earth Science SE**. You can also add links to other profiles or to an Area51 profile.
2. Why you think they/you would be a good candidate.
3. If you are nominating yourself, please add a little bit about you, why you would be a good candidate, and if you really have the time and devotion to guide this community, when it's fun, and when it's a real pain. Also, you can add a small note if you want to help our site by [insert something such as fix tag duplicates].

Post each user as a separate answer, and add multiple answers if you wish to nominate multiple users. Do not make duplicates of nominations.

Additionally, if someone nominates *you*, please **edit the answer** to indicate your approval (or declination). If you want to, add a paragraph or two about yourself so we can get to know you.

If you downvote a particular nomination, you are encouraged to share why you did so in the comments, though you are not required to do so. Optionally, you may do the same for upvotes. This gives gives a candidate a chance to either fight an accusation that is false, or gives you the chance to point out why they should not be a mod. In the end, the SE team doesn't seem to look at the votes, they only look at the actual nomination. If the candidate gets mad at you, that proves *even more* that they wouldn't be a good moderator, so **feel free to express your views.**

For more information, see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

---

### A small note from a not so small mod:

**Being a moderator is tough work.** It seems like an easy job, but there is much more than you see from the surface. It's most disappointing IMHO when a user gets mad and leaves the site for good. It feels like, even if you followed "standard operating procedure", that you did something wrong. Don't get me wrong: it's one of the most amazing feelings to watch a community grow and know that if you weren't there [and no one filled your place], it probably wouldn't have been as successful. That + some occasional swag + talking to some devs (pretty cool) + the diamond makes it worth it.

You'll need time and commitment to fulfill this job. You'll be subject to a lot of naughty words. You'll be sad and upset sometimes. This quote pretty much sums it up:

> I should ask this to some others as well, but it seems you're focusing on the "fun and games" side of moderation. While certainly helpful and appreciated, you will at some point also have to deal with the downsides of being a moderator. Dealing with upset users for example. You will no doubt upset some at some point. How do you see yourself handling that? Are you up to that task?

I've said this to a couple different users, and one of them pinged me a few weeks after saying that I was right that moderatorship isn't all fun and games, when he didn't even get a diamond; he were working with another moderator on another site. :) He, like me at first [with an actual ♦], after that initial surprise still found it worthwhile helping the site.

---

### Optional Template:

```
## I'm Nominating: {Username OR "Myself, {UsernameHere}"} ##

**Links:** [Main (1 Rep)](www.example.com), [Meta](www.meta.example.com), [Other Sites Here (100K Rep, Moderator)](www.othersite.example.com)

{Put Flair Here if you want}
*****
I am a good candidate because... I do... I want...
*****
{Optional (remove the "****" above if you aren't doing this): Getting to know you here}
```

Comment: How many nominations are needed/wanted?

Comment: @naught101 Usually 3 moderators are chosen, but feel free to nominate as many people who you think would do a good job with it.

Comment: Should we delete nominations that are declined?

Comment: @gerrit No, don't. At the very most, downvote it and/or make the decline more obvious. However, we don't want someone to renominate a person who declined.

Comment: I'm wondering how much vote bias there is here: the rankings have remained fairly static, and I wonder if that's to do with higher voted answers being at the top? Or older acceptances getting a head start (none of us know much about each other really). I'm not concerned about the results (the top ranked nominees all seem like they'll do fine), I just think it's interesting.

Comment: @naught101 I bet it's some of both. BTW votes don't really count unless it's 25 then 4 votes or it's -5 or below votes. The SE team doesn't really take votes into account as far as I can tell.

Comment: @naught101 IMHO that's a problem with answers on SE in general. But that's a much bigger topic that's probably been discussed to death on meta.SO before ;-)

Comment: higher voted answers are at the top only if you choose to sort the page by votes.

Comment: @plannapus: right, but for polling like this, it should be sorted randomly.

Comment: @naught101 that's a good point. It is the case with real moderator elections but those elections (at least on stackoverflow) don't use the meta site. Polls are maybe too rare to actually implement a different system for them. But if you think that should be done you should probably ask for it on [meta.SE].

Comment: @plannapus IMHO it'd be pointless because votes are pretty much irreverent to who SE picks in my experience. It'd be a lot of work and would need a specific tag for mods only, and it would only used once when it's not at all needed.

Answer (score 23):

### [hichris123](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/20/hichris123)

[image: profile for hichris123 at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for hichris123 at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for hichris123 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3046327.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/3046327/hichris123)

I don't think I need to say much. Over the last six months, I've worked extensively with hichris on the [Charcoal project](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/), and it's been an awesome experience. I would have no reservations in giving him an increased role on this site.

---

#### Accept

First of all, thank you for nominating me. I'm quite honored that people think of me as a good fit for being a moderator.

Earth Science is an interesting topic for me. I'm still a student, so I don't know everything about it, but I still know quite a bit. This is one of those sites that will keep me coming back, because I see a lot of interesting questions here, and I learn a lot from it.

I'm active on other sites on the Stack Exchange network, such as Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, and some new beta sites like Arduino and Software Recommendations. I know quite a bit about Stack Exchange, but I'm fairly new to the topic of moderation - I haven't gotten the '10k tools' yet on any site.

I'm fairly confident there's some people on this site who would be better moderators than I would (watch out, I'm nominating you next! :P). I think I can learn on the job though, and I have some other Stack Exchange moderators who I chat with and can get their opinions if I'm not too sure on what to do.

I would like to see this community succeed. I would like to help lead it into graduation, as I think it would make a fine addition into the full Stack Exchange network. I'm also active on meta, and will be in this site's chatroom most of the time.

Comment: I haven't worked with him on Charcoal itself (particularly because of my laziness: I haven't set up Github on my new computer :P), but I often hang out in the same chatrooms as him. I also agree that he would be a particularly exceptional candidate because he is very committed to SE in general and he has two moderators to go to if he needs help, not including the entire TL chatroom.

Comment: I highly support this candidate! hichris is active in the same chatrooms that I often am, talking about SE and mod-y stuff, and he's definitely dedicated to moderating SE and would make a great mod for ES. Vote for hichris!

Comment: In discussions I've recently had with him in chat and meta, I think he would make a great moderator. He has shown great temperament, even in slightly heated discussions about the scope of the site.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson I'm highly offended you left me out :P (granted, I'm more of a quieter person, but I am there!)

Comment: @Seth I don't talk about myself in the third person, so yeah, three mods :P

Answer (score 22):

### [gerrit](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/6/gerrit)

[image: profile for hichris123 at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for gerrit at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for gerrit on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/935589.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/935589/gerrit)

gerrit has been noticeably active since the definition phase of this project, is one of the most active users on the site and on meta, and has a strong background on SE in general, and is also currently undertaking post-doctoral studies in a relevant field (atmospheric remote sensing). While I don't know gerrit in any other arena, his approach to the site seems very level-headed and helpful.

---

### Accept

I am honoured by the nomination, and I accept.  What is written above is correct.  I have been active on Stack Exchange for a couple of years now, with some reputation-earned moderation experience on the Academia beta and formerly the Travel beta (before it graduated).  Outside Stack Exchange, I have some experience on moderating occasionally difficult IRC channels (where I experienced that it is *impossible* to do it right; there will *always* be people complaining).  My thoughts on moderation:

- A moderator should do as little as possible, but no less.  I hope the moderation team will not need to use their special powers, but if they really have to, then they must.
- A moderator does not act alone, but as part of a team.  That goes without saying.
- A moderator should stay out of personal conflicts.  Should personal conflicts still happen, he or she should delegate to the other moderators to decide on appropriate action.

Finally, I very much want this site to succeed, and I am happy to use some of my spare time to help make this happen.

Comment: I also like this nomination.

Comment: You seem to really want this position. From experience: if you want the moderator position just to be moderator, you're looking at it all wrong. *Just my 2 cents :)* You do have some decent experience... Something I learned as SE mod: a moderator will have to use their powers on any site, even if it's cleaning up comments. Count on using them in the first week, if not on the first day. Maintaining a community requires a little more than just removing bad users/deleting spam. What about retagging? Editing help docs? Changing close reasons? Aside from that, you seem to be a great candidate.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Actually, I did think before accepting the nomination.  Would it be better to respond with "I'm not too eager, but if you *insist*..."?  I concede that I have not been a moderator on SE before, so perhaps my impression is too optimistic and I view the role as a moderator as more humble than it is.  I think a site is not built by moderators; it is built by users (including moderators).  The amount of work moderators need to do depends very much on the community.  Each SE is different.  How much the moderators will need to use their diamond powers, that remains to be seen.

Comment: +1 (I upvoted a few hours ago, but was too busy to comment. :P) I would have nominated you if someone else wouldn't have. You seem to be very active on the site, and would be a great moderator.

Comment: @gerrit Haha no... Since you're probably going to be picked (as of now), I wanted to verify that you were up for the job, especially since IRC and SE moderation is vastly different. Mod is a tough job, and I wanted to make sure that you weren't just doing this for the diamond, you want to do this *for the site.* If you think you have the time and you want to do this mostly for helping the site, I think you would be a great candidate.

Comment: I have no doubt Gerrit will carry out the mod aspect of the task with the fair-handed and efficient manner I have seen him display elsewhere. My only (slight) doubt would be that his trajectory into Earth Sciences may perhaps have not given him the breadth of knowledge to call upon when the site is still defining what is and isn't on topic in the initial weeks (although the same would also be true of those still studying). I also don't know if he is able to devote the time required if the role becomes a demanding one.

Comment: @Siv: I think that is true of any individual: there are too many fields here for anyone to be across all of them.

Comment: I think it's important that moderators have good domain knowledge, plenty of active engagement in the meat of the site (not just the management of it), and some human connections in the field. @gerrit also seems to do a decent job of avoiding unsavoury Internet jousting contests. Last thing: I value being able to read a person's profile.

Answer (score 12):

### [casey](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/64/casey)

[image: profile for casey at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]


[image: profile for casey at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]


[profile for casey on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3672166.png?](http://stackexchange.com/users/3672166)


[image: profile for casey at Aviation Stack Exchange, Q&A for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts]

casey has been an active user since the start of the private beta and has shown an interest in the site. casey has supplied excellent responses thus far and has experience in computer modeling and meteorology (including participation in [VORTEX2](https://www.nssl.noaa.gov/projects/vortex2/)) and is pursuing a PhD in meteorology. casey has over 10k reputation across the SE network.

---

### Accept

Thank you for the nomination.  This is not something I take lightly, but given the amount of time I spend here, I think I can be of use to benefit our site.  I don't have any SE (diamond) mod experience, but through the Aviation.SE beta I have become familiar with the 10k tools and the expanded deletion/undeletion privileges given to 20k users.  To show my commitment to that beta, hop on over to the A51 page and you'll find me as the 5th most active user for the 120 days that site has been in beta.  Aviation is my old job and meteorology my current passion, so you'll find I give the same level of commitment to this site.  I am also constantly in chat and users will always be able to communicate with me directly.

I'm familiar with the SE Theory of Moderation, and I view moderation here as an exception handler.  We already have a small contingent of 500 rep users with access to the open/close queue and a few 1k-ers that have full access including the suggested edit queue.  Before long we'll have some 2k-ers that can access flags and cast delete votes.  It is these users that I'll rely on to run the site and my role will be to assist them and handle any issues they can't directly take care of, as well as be our sites voice (along with the other mods) to SE.

---

Answer (score 9):

### I'm Nominating: [Simon W](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/39/Simon-W)

[image: profile for Simon W at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for Simon W at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for Simon W on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/888036.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/888036/SimonW)

[profile for Simon W at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/96331.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/96331/SimonW)

---

Simon W has been an active participant and has shown an interest in the site.
He has [domain expertise](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/introduce-yourselves-here/20#20) and [some cross-site experience](http://stackexchange.com/users/888036/simon-w?tab=accounts).  He has been [active on meta early on](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39/simon-w), having [earned the convention badge before anybody else](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/convention).

---

Hmm.

### Tentatively accept

I feel that I am lacking in SE experience (although that can come through guidance from others with more) - I'm only over 1k on one site, although I do have experience of being a citizen in (sometimes contentious) online communities since the 90s. I had not self-nominated because I think there are probably better candidates out there. But, if the community feels otherwise, I'll accept that wisdom and give it my best shot ;-) Let's see how the votes pan out.

I've been vocal over certain issues in meta, which are largely moot now that we're public. However, there has been nothing personal in the views that I have expressed, and I have refrained from taking any action (such as close votes) without a consensus. I hope that that is clear to anybody perusing the last few weeks' worth of debate.

I would not promise not to have opinions as a mod. However, I would commit to making clear whether I was speaking in a personal capacity or with a "mod hat" on, and I would not attempt to enforce my opinions without consensus.

Views:

- I am in favour of light-touch moderation. Better to speak with people to try to integrate a community than to use tools. However, sometimes one has to take action anyway, preferably after consulting with other mods. I suspect that this point is the mod-election equivalent of "I believe in world peace".
- Except in clearcut spam cases, I would be considerably more cautious about voting on closes and the like with a diamond than without, since it bypasses community voting.
- I am strongly against closing questions without explanation. As a relatively new user to SE, I know how demoralising and alienating that can be. That isn't to say that I'm afraid to take action, with or without a diamond, but that I would take pains to explain things, and I would encourage others to do the same.

That's all I can think of; please feel free to ask questions. I will be travelling for a conference for most of the next ~10 days, so replies may not be immediate. Use @SimonW to make sure I get a notification.

Answer (score 7):

### I'm Nominating: [Neo](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/32/Neo)

[image: profile for Neo at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for Neo at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for Neo on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2395179.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/2395179/Neo)

[profile for Neo at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/105629.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/105629.png)

Neo has been an active participant and has shown an interest in the site.

---

## **Accept**

Thank you for nominating me.

I would be a bit weary of accepting this position if receiving enough up votes: I haven't been super active on another SE (though I plan to be active here). My inexperience I think would make me less suitable than others. Though if called on I would accept, and welcome the challenge.

I would clearly defer to the other 2 moderators, especially in the beginning, as the likely suggested ones are clearly more familiar with SE.

I am a graduate student in Earth Sciences, though have never actually taken an Earth Science class other than the subjects that are relevant to my thesis. My original interest in this site stemmed from that very narrow knowledge, and am hoping that interesting questions (which they have) will help me catch up to my peers. I enjoy the spirited debate that has occurred often on this site.

Working to preserve this community and debate is a worthy cause, and easily worthy of my time.

Comment: @Geodude Can you please reference any of these incidents?

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, Neo voted to close several questions in the first few days of the site, which have since been re-opened (It won't allow me to see which questions now, but several of my questions included).  I consider the fact that these questions had multiple up votes and were re-opened within 1-2 days as evidence that these close votes weren't warranted.  This is my main concern.  Neo has been critical vocally of these questions in chat, but that is OK.  What is not OK is then acting to close questions that are in fact on-topic and of high quality.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, and the rest of the community. I will not deny the fact that I have voted to close a few topics on this site. My criticisms for those questions, were generally very basic: If you are going to ask basic questions, ask them in a way where the person who answers can address specific misconceptions about a phenomena. I felt that these questions, in their current form, were asking for a wikipediaesque response which to my young understanding of SE is not appropriate. Reopened questions were often edited; And I am not the only one who voted to close these questions.

Comment: @Neo, re-opened questions were also often not edited.  I believe you are too trigger happy on the close votes and moderation powers may be abused.

Comment: @Neo, I also have an issue with you answering several questions, and then voting to close them, preventing the asker from deleting the questions that are inappropriate.  If such questions should be closed, you shouldn't answer them to begin with.

Comment: @Neo, why do you feel the need to edit out pictures that add to an anwer?  In this post:  http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/403/phase-changes-deep-in-planetary-interiors-and-their-implications-for-surface-tec, you edited the picture out, but I believe the picture enables readers to instantly see what the "tiger stripes" are without having to google elsewhere.  I think as a moderator you will force such edits, downgrading the quality of the site.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, in chat Neo claims that he deleted the picture because it wasn't referenced.  However why can't Neo have simply made a comment asking for a reference, or an edit adding a caption to the picture.  Instead he resorted to the more drastic change of deleting the picture entirely.  I have since reverted the change, and after discussing with Neo, I will add a caption.  But I don't understand why he couldn't have made this suggestion prior to initial deletion.  I worry this will occur as a moderator.  Immediate action, without explanations first.

Comment: *Sighs* @Geodude First of all, I do agree that he/she could have added a comment first. However, citations are *expected* on SE and no citations could get SE in legal trouble, so it's a moot point. Advice for Neo: it's generally expected to leave a comment when you do action on a post, and [if you're a mod] you even consider it. Also, as far as the close votes, 4 people had to agree with Neo's views that we shouldn't have broad questions to even close the question in the first place.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, duly noted. Though Geodude pointed out specific examples of my inexperience, So hopefully people will take that into account if they want to up vote me for moderator. It was not my intention to cause such conflict.

Comment: @Neo No need to duly note anything :) I was just mentioning that, in the future, you should comment whenever voting for close or any other "moderator like" action. I think that, once you get the hang of mod, you'll do great, I was just pointing that out. I don't know how I would've handled the picture thing, personally; I would've asked around a bit.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, I understand 4 people agreed with his views (bust most people didn't agree, because the questions were re-opened and up-voted heavily).  That said, most people who agreed with Neo had low reputation, and wouldn't have had the power to vote to close on public beta anyway which requires 500 rep.  I also wouldn't support EnergyNumbers and BHF as moderators on Earth.SE for the same reason I don't support Neo.

Comment: @Geodude Neo has enough rep to vote on closing in public (IIRC). Also, votes don't mean that it's on topic. I've seen random spam get +15 votes on SO. They're two different factors.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, but immediate re-opening of most of the questions Neo voted to close AND lots of up-votes does say something.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, yes I understand that Neo has the power to close, but I don't want him to have additional moderation powers in addition to the diamond which new users will respect, knowing his overly tough approach to what questions are off-topic.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, I beg you to pick Tom Au over Neo.  Tom Au has a vast experience, and is more level headed with regards to what is and isn't on topic.

Comment: @Geo I don't pick who gets moderator status. That's up to the SE team. However, as far as I'm concerned, you still haven't given examples of one of these posts. You're giving *your opinion*. You may be right, but I haven't seen enough evidence so far as to why they would be a bad mod.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, As a moderator, can't you see which questions Neo has voted to close?  I can't because they have been re-opened since so that data is gone.  But I think every question of mine that was closed Neo had voted for it, and they have all been re-opened except 1 or 2 which have remained closed and rightly so.  My point is those other questions would have remained closed if he was a moderator.  Let anyone be a moderator but Neo, please!

Comment: Some examples are [this question](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/236/will-the-earth-ever-stop-rotating), [this question](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/245/is-it-true-that-a-butterfly-flapping-its-wings-can-result-in-a-tornado-in-a-dist), [this question](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/244/is-a-mega-tsunami-that-will-destroy-america-inevitable), and [this question](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/243/what-causes-a-volcano) (This one rightly closed in my opinion, but why did Neo answer it before casting his close vote?)

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, these are just my questions that I suspect Neo voted to close.  I would have to have special permissions to see if that is indeed the case since we can no longer see who voted to close them since some of them have been re-opened.  I'm pretty sure other similar questions from other users were also closed by Neo and later re-opened.

Comment: Here are all the posts i've closed: http://postimg.org/image/okrfhm2sv/. In my opinion, you went on a streak of questions that were not in the scope of this website. Since then, since we worked together in chat on how to form good questions ( you even thanked me) I have not closed another post. If this continues, I will take it personally, as In my opinion the tone of your confrontation is unprofessional. I am sorry If I have so vigorously offended you.

Comment: @Neo, in your opinion, you still believe those questions should be closed, yet most of them that were closed have been re-opened rightfully so.  If you were a moderator, these on-topic community approved questions would be closed because a moderator's closure vote results in immediate closure.  Now this is slightly personal, because we each have different visions for the future of the site.  Your vision differs significantly to mine, and I believe your vision is not in the best interests of the ultimate success of this site.

Comment: @Neo, My vision is for a site that is useful as a repository of knowledge and a learning tool for both beginners and experts, but your vision seems to be for a site that caters for just experts, and to send beginners off to wikipedia to learn.  I want this site to include both questions from beginners and experts, and have the site act as a stepping stone, at all levels, to increased knowledge of the Earth sciences.

Comment: An observation : just because somebody has voted in a particular way when they a normal user and are aware that a consensus (or at least more votes) will be required to produce an action, does not mean that they would vote the same way as a moderator, when they know that their "vote" would have immediate effect. Obviously I can't speak for Neo, but I and I imagine many people would aim to be far more hands-off and far less opinion-driven with a diamond.

Comment: @SimonW, that is why Simon I would vote for you, but I wouldn't vote for Neo.  Neo has yet to express in anyway that he would be less hands-off as a moderator, as the other candidates have expressed.

Comment: @Geodude, from my original post "I would clearly defer to the other 2 moderators, especially in the beginning, as the likely suggested ones are clearly more familiar with SE."

Comment: @Geodude I may have not made this clear enough but I'm a moderator on *another site*. I've just been interested in this site and am a moderator on Arduino SE. I've looked through the questions, and I agree that some of them should be left open. The volcano one, yes, should be closed.

Comment: Simon was correct that many mods won't vote the same way after getting moderator. After reviewing the closed questions, it seems like those were closed because they weren't expert level questions. IMO there's a bit in the help that's confusing. You don't want basic questions at the beginning, but that doesn't mean they should be closed. @Neo Advice: if you do become moderator, just try to step back with voting unless it's *purely obvious* that it's off topic or it's too vague until the site gets a "rhythm" of closing questions. I would give this advice to *any* mod, don't take it personally :)

Answer (score 4):

### I'm Nominating: [naught101](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/56/naught101)

[image: profile for naught101 at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for naught101 at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for naught101 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/73202.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/73202/naught101)

[profile for naught101 at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/52202.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/52202.png)

---

naught101 has been an active participant and has shown an interest in the site.
Xe is active on many Stack Overflow sites and has been for a very long
time.  Xe has referred nine users to the commitment, which shows xe is very interested to make this site succeed.

---

### Accept

On the basis that people should have some choice among moderators (I think there are better nominations than mine). I have time to work on this site, and am very keen to see it succeed.

I've just started a PhD in climate/land surface modelling, with a heavy focus on statistical analysis. My work hasn't taken me far into the realm of theoretical biogeophyics yet, hence the lack of land surface questions on the site - more will come :)

As a moderator,  I'm comfortable with all the duties specified in the post and follow up comments on other nominations. I have a tendency to prefer to leave questions open where there is any ambiguity about the suitability to the site (this is why I'm not sure my nomination is best - this isn't a view that seems to be shared by the majority of the SE moderator community). I'm also very keen to see *constructive* criticism given whenever a question is closed, such that the poster feels that the question can be improved and re-opened, or a new, more suitable question can be asked.

Answer (score 2):

### [Tom Au](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/42/tom-au)

[image: profile for hichris123 at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for gerrit at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for gerrit on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/512193.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/512193/tom-au)

Tom Au has made valuable contributions in both the main site and the meta site. Tom Au also a strong background in the SE network having accumulated a whopping 21k in reputation in the history SE site and 61k of reputation overall.  I therefore believe with all of Tom's experience, wisdom and knowledge, if he accepts, will make an excellent moderator.

---

### Accept

I am deeply honored to be nominated for a moderator position by a high reputation member of the Earth Sciences site.

I accept the nomination with the knowledge that the site already has several acceptances from candidates, [hichris123](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/138/169), [gerrit](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/142/169), and [neo](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/150/169), and [geodude](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/51/), for whom I have a great deal of respect. Basically, I'll be glad to serve if the site would like to utilize another moderator, but am prepared to "stand down" if the preference is for three or four, all of whom I consider better than myself.

My strength is based on my long participation on other SE sites, and on metas, both on those sites, and Earth Sciences. Hence I could be a "go to" person when the question is, "what have others done in similar situations elsewhere?"

On the Earth Sciences site itself, I have a decent, but by no means superlative, reputation. Barely ranking in the top third or so of 33 "avid" users, I cannot claim "expertise" or even "comparative advantage" in the subject matter. I believe that my knowledge of process and protocol could compensate for what I lack in technical knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

### I'm Nominating: [DrewP84](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/38/DrewP84)

[image: profile for DrewP84 at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for DrewP84 at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for DrewP84 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1582140.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1582140/DrewP84)

[profile for DrewP84 at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/106743.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/106743.png)

---

DrewP84 has been an active participant and has shown an interest in the site.

---

### Declined (by comment)

> I enjoy participating on this site, but I do not have the time to commit to this. Thanks, though.

*DrewP84*

Answer (score 2):

### I'm Nominating: [Peter Jansson](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/81/Peter_Jansson)

[image: profile for Peter Jansson at Earth Science Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for Peter Jansson at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]
[profile for Peter Jansson on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1894359.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1894359/Peter_Jansson)

[profile for Peter Jansson at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/71167.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/71167.png)

---

Peter Jansson has been an active participant and has shown an interest in the site.
I know him very well from Academia.SE, where he is among the most active users overall.

---

### Decline

I am very honoured to be asked to moderate the Earth Sciences, but I am afraid I must decline. The reason is that stated by in a comment below by Simon W. I believe the group of moderators should be able to spend time on their tasks and I think I will only be able to do so intermittently. I am of course keen to see the site prosper and support whoever becomes elected.

Keep asking, answering and most importantly upvote

Comment: While I am impressed by Peter's credentials (and his participation to date), I am concerned that a full professor may not have the time to be an effective moderator. I may be wrong however - I hope that he will come and reassure me :-)